# UIAccelerometer is Shaking

Tags: iphone, uiaccelerometer

I want a functionality in which i want to detect if my device is being shaked.The problem is i can detect the shake with didAccelerate method of UIAcceleratorDelegate , but i dont know how to detect if the device is still shaking. I want to play an audio file when the user shakes the device for first time,i have to check if the user is still shaking the device while playing the 1st audio file,if it is still being shaked, then i have to play another file.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider writing a Method that runs in a separate thread that polls wether your device is being shaken every now and then and fire events that you handle somewhere else in your code (or instead of that, handle whatever you want to handle within the threads context itself, even tough i would not recommend doing that).

You just have to make sure, that your "shake-detektor"-thread exits at some point in time, you probably want to do that when the second audio file stopped playing. So your loop could test on that condition.

Hope I could help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

See the sample project [GLPaint](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GLPaint/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007328-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_11) from Apple which was found by visiting http://developer.apple.com/iphone and entering "shake" in the search box. Developer account not required.